# Open new tab by ctrl + click in VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using `VSCode` for the angular project and every time if I have an error, I can't open the error file by `ctrl + click` the error file name in the terminal. `Ctrl + Click` is a new window it opens a new `VSCode` and How can I change this to open a new tab?

I have been annoyed by this feature and I can't find where is the shortcut for an open new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Open VsCode, press F1, Search open user settings, click on open user settings. a window will come. search terminal on left and try turning off allowchords to false.

[image]

Comment: still open the new window